# Recursively calculates the lines to draw

Tags: java, recursion

So basically I have a method that will recursively calculate lines to draw.

It basically doing this:

```
if(size == 2) unit /= 2;
if(size == 2 || size == 6) unit /= 2;
if(size == 2 || size == 6 || size == 10) unit /= 2;
```

So there is a pattern happening. It check if size is equal to the last size + 4. Starting from 2.

I want to know how to do this recursively .

This is the method

```
public void recurs()
{
    if(size >= SIZE) return;
    //Write recursive method here

    recurs();
}
```

SIZE is equal to 256.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JornVernee I meant recurs not descend.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
public void recurse(int size)
{
    if(size >= SIZE) return;
    unit /= 2;
    recurse(size + 4);
}
```

Then call with `recurse(2);`

But this recursive algorithm is solvable to:

```
unit /= Math.pow(2, ((SIZE - 2) / 4) + 1);
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without adding a parameter?

Comment: I edited the question, apparently it already calls recurse(); at the end.

Comment: @ShawnSmith Something has to change from call to call. So if it's not a parameter, it would be a class field, which I wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
public int compute(int unit) {
    if((unit - 2) % 4 == 0) 
        return compute(unit / 2);
    return unit;
}
```

Comment: I edited the question, apparently it already calls recurse(); at the end.